# XCode & SPM - Resolve Package Dependency dynamically

Tags: xcode, swift-package-manager

Is there a way to specify a dynamic 'Version Rule' when adding an SPM dependency ? I'd need one of my packages to resolve to the same branch name as my project's current branch.

For example:

- App: develop

  - sdk: $(CURRENT_BRANCH) -> Resolves to develop

I was looking through XCode env variables but there doesn't seem to be any mention of VCS branches. That, and anyway it doesn't look like using a variable to specify the 'Version Rule' interpolates when resolving the dependency graph...

I tried with `$(MARKETING_VERSION)` just to see if it would, but I'm getting this output:

```
<redacted>/SourcePackages/repositories/ios_sdk-c1e27c7e 
    rev-parse 
    --verify '$(MARKETING_VERSION)^{commit}' 
output:

fatal: Needed a single revision
```